# Create file with session ID and a counter name

Tags: php

I am trying to run a PHP script which enable users to create File and save them on the Server with following naming convention:

```
$i =1 ;
$fileName  = 'txt'. session_id() . $i . ".txt" ;
$i++;
```

Output:

> txtmtbd6146ljq9fhd7sindi3njj1.txt

Here is the code I have

```
<?php
session_start();

$i = $_SESSION['views']=1;
$fileName  = 'txt'. session_id() . $i ;
// increase for next saving as a user may save many
$i++;

$theFileName = $fileName".txt";
$theFileHandle = fopen($theFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fclose($theFileHandle);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you probably have to write some contents before closing...?

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for reply .please no worry for that part for now. what I need is creating a counter to be added to the end of file name for now

Comment: shouldn't be that you're incrementing whats inside of the file instead of the filename? because what will happen is that you'll just spawn a new file in every refresh with the same session id

Comment: Hi Ghost, I am not sure , honestly. what I want to do is incrementing  the file name

Comment: well, if that's want you want then, just make you have proper permissions to write

Comment: Also, post code you have actually executed. Line 7 has an error; no semi.

Comment: I do indeed. right now I am creating file there but I need to add a number to the end of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whats missing on your code is you're not incrementing the views. Example:

```
session_start();
$path = 'user_counters_folder/';
// initialize counter
if(!isset($_SESSION['views'])) {
    $_SESSION['views'] = 1;
} else {
    // increment
    ++$_SESSION['views'];
}

$fileName = 'txt'. session_id() . $_SESSION['views'];
$theFileName = $fileName . '.txt';
$theFileHandle = fopen($path . $theFileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($theFileHandle, $_SESSION['views']);
fclose($theFileHandle);
```

Sidenote: Make sure you have permissions to write.

My suggestion is instead of creating a file with the session id and the increment for each same session. Write the session id as a filename instead, then put the counter inside the file.

Comment: Can you please also let me know how to do that and what is the benefit of that over this one?

Comment: @MonaCoder actually its not a benefit, it think that would be the logical way to do it, since you're writing on the same file on the same session (means you're writing on 1 file per session), instead of spawning multiple files for each same session.

Comment: Oh, I got it now. actually what I need is exactly what you already fix since the file will store some different info from different queries each time. Once again thanks